# Missing memory usage on processes list

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, task-manager, memory-leaks

Current memory used based on Task Manager processes list is around 2gb since google chrome is the most memory hungry on the list.

[image]

But on performance tab, I've been using 7gb.
[image]

Is there something or hidden processes that consumes my memory? Noticed this because once I open Premiere pro, it goes to 90%+ full even though it should be around 50% based on the list of processes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: RAMMap will give you a better view.  I would suggest post a screenshot of that.  The Channel 9 video linked at the bottom of the page is worth watching.

Comment: Hi @HelpingHand, added an edit :)

Comment: Could you add the Use Counts tab?

Comment: @HelpingHand done, thanks

Comment: I've posted in the answer section as it's too much for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Task Manager value of "In use" is the Active physical memory, or working set in use. In this case 6GB of your 16GB total is Active. Everything else is really just "waiting in the wings".

As the zeroed is only 140K it tells us that at sometime since boot, all your memory has been used. Some of that has obviously been ejected from Active but left in Standby or Modified so it can be re-used if needed. This is like a cache, so you want Standby/Modified to be well populated as it will cause a soft page fault to bring the data back into Active which is fast. If it's not in the "cache" then it will incur a hard fault when required, which will have to bring it in from the page file or disk which is slow. So Standby and Modified being high is mainly good especially if it's data that's likely to be re-used.

Your Process Private of 3.3 GB is your programs and it's all Active which is good. This looks expected.

Mapped files of 11GB, this is how much data of image files have been read from disk.  Most is in standby so it's ready to be brought back into active quickly if needed. The longer a machine has been up the higher this will be.

Your Paged Pool and non-paged is fine. Neither suggest a driver leak. These are fine at those levels especially if the computer has been up for a few days. Without any new drivers that could introduce a leak or high pool usage, these should be roughly the same after 1 day and say 2 days of uptime.

It all looks OK and I would expect the uptime (which you can see on the CPU page in Task Manager) would be at least a few hours to have mapped file value so high and use the RAM such that there is nothing in zeroed.  What is the uptime out of interest?

Comment: thank you for the explanation, uptime usually runs during working hours (morning till afternoon). Noticed this kind of performance once I tried doing some premiere pro tasks, it almost doesn't move when I scrolling on the timeline because the memory reaches 99% occupancy even though this app and chrome are the only software running. Been editing videos using this up before without any hassle, most of the time with other apps like photoshop, etc.